# Creating json using jackson and ignoring object in some condition

Tags: java, jackson

i want to apply @JsonIgnore in some condition only .

for example in one case i may only need test object not all the questions in test.
  but in other case i may required to have all the question as well by using        `@JsonManagedReference`

```
class Test{
      private string testName; 
      @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="abc")
      @JsonIgnore
      private Set<question> question;
 }
```

Comment: This won't compile, unless you meant a `Set` and not a `set`

Comment: Just have two classes?

Comment: @mach it is just a demo object it can have other objects

Answer (score 1):

Try out @JsonView.  It allows you to conditionally include/suppress properties based on a view (a marker class) that is provided during serialization.

```
class Test {
    private String testName;

    @JsonView(SomeCondition.class)
    private Set<Question> questions;
}

@GET
@Path("/testWithCondition")
@JsonView(SomeCondition.class)
public Response getTestWithCondition() {
    Test test = testService.lookupTest();
    return Response.ok(test).build();
}
```

**Note:** You may have to disable MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION on your ObjectMapper.